# Best practice for protecting against Denial of Service(DoS) attacks in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, denial-of-service

I'm looking for best practice advice/guidance (perhaps from Microsoft?) regarding denial of service (DoS) protection/mitigation for ASP.NET Core web applications.

The main two options I have found so far are:

- [AspNetCoreRateLimit](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit) (ASP.NET Core middleware)
- [Dynamic IP Restrictions](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/dynamic-ip-restrictions) (IIS module - assuming the site is hosted in IIS).

It seems like there are a number of pros and cons to consider when choosing one of these options over the other, so it would be good to understand what those are, and indeed if AspNetCoreRateLimit is intended to be used alongside Dynamic IP Restrictions or not.

Also note that AspNetCoreRateLimit is not part of ASP.NET Core releases from Microsoft, therefore I'm curious to know what Microsoft's official guidance is.

Comment: Are you running a reverse proxy in front of your ASP.NET core application? like HAProxy or Nginx? If you aren't, you should consider it and should consider defense in depth by allowing your reverse proxy to handle those requests before they hit your application server -- the reason being that you can still crowd out requests by spiking the CPU of the application server, so it's not really feasible to ask the application server to handle DOS attacks. For us to answer this question, we need to know whether your application is 'cloud native' or architected so that you control the whole stack.

Comment: Plain and simple: this isn't an ASP.NET Core thing. It needs to be handled at the network level: a firewall, WAF, ingress controller, proxy server, etc. If it gets to the ASP.NET Core app, it's already too late.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a public facing website and want to prevent DDoS, doing it outside your ASP Core app would be the best method. You should investigate services like [ClouldFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/).